# traefik reverse proxy

Tags: proxy, devops, traefik

Каким образом в конфиге по ссылке, [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/) понимает, что все запросы должны проксироваться на **5000** порт. Явно этого нигде не указывается. Но по факту, почему-то при переходе по mydomain.com, я вижу **Hello World**. Как так происходит?

Конфиг

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[web]
address = ":8080"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "test@traefik.io"
storageFile = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onDemand = false
OnHostRule = true
  # Use a HTTP-01 acme challenge rather than TLS-SNI-01 challenge
  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "example.com"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

Замечу, что в примере по ссылке используется версия 1.7, хотя явно этого не указывается. Поэтому ниже привожу компоуз модифицированный:

```
version: '2'
services:
  flask:
    build: ./flask
    image: flask
    command: uwsgi --http-socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --wsgi-file app.py --callable app
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=flask"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=${TRAEFIK_FRONTEND_RULE}"
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.7.24
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml:ro
      - ./traefik/acme:/etc/traefik/acme
    ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:443"
     - "8080:8080"
```

Ещё [ссылка](https://github.com/uSasha/pydata_demo/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) на traefik reverse proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема крылась в `docker-compose`. Для `traefik` нужно устанавливать `port`, который будет слушать приложение, которое доступно по доменному имени:

```
version: '2'
services:
  flask:
    build: ./flask
    image: flask
    command: uwsgi --http-socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --wsgi-file app.py --callable app
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=flask"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=${TRAEFIK_FRONTEND_RULE}"
      - "traefik.frontend.port=5000"
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.7.24
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml:ro
      - ./traefik/acme:/etc/traefik/acme
    ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:443"
     - "8080:8080"
```

Либо же, его нужно делать явным образом `EXPOSE 5000` внутри докера.